# Redirect url to status GONE

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-codes

This one is driving me crazy. Whatever I do, it doesn't say the page is GONE.
Full url will be something like: `example.com/product_detail.php?id=18`

I want to give every page that starts with product_details.php the status GONE.

I thought that one of these would work, but no luck

```
RewriteRule ^product_detail - [G]
RewriteRule ^product_detail.php?id=(.*)$ - [G]
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Works for me, though the second rule isn't needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on John Lin's comment I moved the RewriteRule to the top of the htaccess and then it was working. Further testing revealed that when I put the RewriteRule below Wordpress' basic lines

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

it doesn't work, but when it is before these lines it works.
Learnt something new today.

Hope it's helpful to others as well.

Comment: well, as I see it, the wordpress block redirects all request to non-files and directories to index.php as a last rule (that's [L], it tells apache to stop processing)  - so after that no matter what you put in to redirect (for non-existent files), it'll not work.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the WP redirects. I'm going to put all redirects  for non-existent files before the WP block.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested if the rule is applied at all?
This works for me:

RewriteRule ^product_detail.*$ - [G]

Do you have the RewriteEngine on in the .htaccess file? (assuming that's what you're using)

Is the rewrite module on in apache?  is it allowed at the given location?